# Calculate the percentage of column data in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have table column like;

```
Documents
------------
1 2 3
1 2
2 3
1
4 5 1 3
```

Data under document column indicates the type of document; for e.g

```
1 indicates passport
2 indicates School id  and so on.....
```

I want the column data as separate data with percentage calculation. like;

Basically i want to show percentage for each data...

```
    Documents     percentage
    -------------------------
    1               10%
    2               2%
    3               1% 
    4               25%
    5               30%
```

I want to show data as separate data with their percentage.

can we build query in postgres to achive this????

Comment: What type is the column?

Comment: In Documents ,is this column structure ?please mention some more info.what you need exactly ?

Comment: Yes its a column .... Basically I want to calculate percentage for each option mentioned under document column

Comment: Klin and pramod can we achive this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with t(s) as ( values
    ('1 2 3'),('1 2'),('2 3'),('1'),('4 5 1 3')
)
select distinct s,
    count(*) over(partition by s) * 100.0 /
    count(*) over() as percentage
from (
    select regexp_split_to_table(s, ' ') as s
    from t
) t
;
 s |     percentage      
---+---------------------
 5 |  8.3333333333333333
 4 |  8.3333333333333333
 3 | 25.0000000000000000
 1 | 33.3333333333333333
 2 | 25.0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the strings to arrays and unnest them, then you can calculate total and percentages:

```
create table test (documents text);
insert into test values
('1 2 3'),
('1 2'),
('2 3'),
('1'),
('4 5 1 3');

with docs as (
    select doc
    from test, unnest(string_to_array(documents, ' ')) doc
    ),
total as (
    select count(*) as total
    from docs
    )
select doc, count(doc), count(doc)* 100/ total as percentage
from docs, total
group by doc, total
order by 1;

 doc | count | percentage 
-----+-------+------------
 1   |     4 |         33
 2   |     3 |         25
 3   |     3 |         25
 4   |     1 |          8
 5   |     1 |          8
(5 rows)
```